# Copy a column into an empty column of another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to copy the value of a column of a table into another column of another table within the same database:

I have tried using this code:

```
UPDATE [db].[dbo].[table]
    SET HAG = (
        SELECT Column1
        FROM [db].[table1]
    )
GO
```

But this only works when apply the TOP(1) function in which case it just copies the first value into the entire column.

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` something like `UPDATE t SET HAG = s.Column1 FROM SourceTable as s INNER JOIN TargetTable as t ON s.key_col = t.key_col`

Comment: Which row do you want to update from? Sample data and desired results might clarify your question.

Comment: `[db].[table1]` "db" is an odd name for a schema; that is probably a typo. Better yet - just don't use three-part names generally. It is a bad habit and makes your code more brittle and subject to errors when the person running that code (i.e., YOU) need to run it against a different set of databases. You need to unlearn this bad habit. There are many good habits and best practices you DO need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is assigning the HAG column value of the entire subquery result set, when it can only store a single value. When you do top 1 it returns only 1 value and that gets assigned. The reason for this is, the subquery will always execute first.

Normally when you append a column like this, its corresponding to an already existing column for example you have a department table and an employee table and you want to append the department table with the employee names. In that case you would have an ID of sort that you can join the 2 tables on and it will be something like this:

```
UPDATE table
set hag = column1
from table inner join table2 on table.id - table1.id
```

But from what I understand you just want to append the column in the table without concerns about the corresponding values. I don't really understand the application for it, but you can do that in this way.

```
with cte as (select column1 from table1)
update table
set hag = cte.column1
```

this should ideally work, but it will populate the new column in whatever order the values from the second table are selected.